# Version of -- Bash? -- During Docker's Build Context

Tags: bash, docker

What shell and what version of that shell does Docker run during the container build phase?

That is -- I have a `Dockerfile` with the following line.

```
RUN /path/to/a/script.bash
```

This runs a script during Docker's build phase.  However, when I build Docker's getting tripped up by some common-to-me bash idioms.  For example, I have the following in my script

```
urls=(
http://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION.tgz
https://downloads.apache.org/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION.tgz
http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION.tgz
http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION.tgz
https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/apache/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION.tgz
)
```

and Docker fails during the build with

```
/path/to/a/script.bash: 11: /path/to/a/script.bash: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

So what shell, and what version of that shell, is Docker using when it runs a script via `RUN`. (or why is that the wrong question to ask?)

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run ?

Comment: Just because the script has `.bash` as an extension doesn't mean it's executed by `bash`. What, if any, shebang is in `script.bash`? The available shell is also determined by whatever base image you are using.

Comment: Does the script start with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: @FelixKling I did, and I didn't see any mention of whether the shell for RUN is the shell of the host machine, the image, or something else.  Did I miss it?

Comment: @chepner -- Thank you -- "The available shell is also determined by whatever base image you are using" is the answer I was looking for.  Happy to mark as best if it's a real answer (and the missing shebang was the culprit in this specific case)

Comment: @JohnKugelman It was not, thank you for that advice.  While this solves the specific problem I had, I'm still curious what shell RUN will default to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify an alternate [`SHELL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell), `RUN` commands that are a bare string are wrapped in `/bin/sh -c` (on Linux).  So these two commands are equivalent:

```
RUN /path/to/a/script.bash
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/path/to/a/script.bash"]
```

What shell that actually runs is a function of the base image.  Often this is a shell that implements what is in the POSIX spec and no more; Alpine-based images don't include the heavier-weight GNU Bash at all unless you explicitly install it.

Also note that this is different from the interpreter needed to run the script, which is typically indicated by the "shebang" line `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the script.  You can `RUN` any script or executable this way so long as it has the right declaration at the top of the file.  If there isn't a `#!` line at all, then the script will be interpreted by the `/bin/sh` from the base image, which is likely to not support the Bash extensions (array variables, `source`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Run `bash --version` in your docker build.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN /bin/bash --version
```

My output:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 1d622ef86b13
Step 2/2 : RUN /bin/bash --version
 ---> Running in c2b2eae0798a
GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Removing intermediate container c2b2eae0798a
---> 4acdc3fa30ea 
Successfully built 4acdc3fa30ea
```

Finally I remove that temporary image `docker image rm 4acdc3fa30ea`.